# Using urllib.parse.urlencode() on a python zip() list of 2-tuple

Tags: python, list, zip, tuples, urlencode

I am trying to use urllib.parse.urlencode() to generate an encoded url for a get request. To do so, I need to use urllib.parse.urlencode() with a list of 2-tuple. I need to generate a dynamic list since the get request is based on the locations entered. This is for a mapquest api get request. I created the dynamic list and the 2-tuple list using zip() but the urllib.parse.urlencode() does not work on the 2-tuple list. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is another way to do this. Thank you.

```
import urllib.parse

add = ''
tolist=[]
newlist = []
locations = ['austin, tx', 'dallas, tx', 'denver, co', 'houston, tx','irving, tx', '3']
for item in range(2,len(locations)-1):
    tolist.append('to')
    newlist.append(locations[item])

print(locations[0])
print('tolist', tolist)
print('newlist', newlist)
zipped=zip(tolist, newlist)

add = add + urllib.parse.urlencode(zipped) 

print()
parselist=[('to', 'denver, co'),('to', 'houston, tx'),('to', 'irving, tx')]
add = add + urllib.parse.urlencode(parselist) #this works
print('add', add)
```

Hi again, sorry, I found the problem and I got it working now. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`##add = add + urllib.parse.urlencode(ziplist) #this does not work`

To:

`add = add + urllib.parse.urlencode(list(zipped))`
`

Comment: Hi, that was commented out on purpose since it does not work.